# coordinates CCTouch Obj-C

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How do I get the coordinates of an touch event in objective-c using cocos2d?

```
- (void)touchBegan:(CCTouch *)touch withEvent:(CCTouchEvent *)event
{
    CCLOG(@"Received a touchBegan");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCTouch (currently missing in the [class reference](http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/index.html) but will be added soon) has methods to get the touch locations:

```
// position in scene coordinates
CGPoint touchPos = [touch locationInWorld];

// touch position relative to anyNode's position
CGPoint touchPosNode = [touch locationInNode:anyNode];
```

**Tip:** In Xcode right-click a keyword such as `CCTouch` and select **Jump to Definition** and it will bring you to the class interface which at least shows you the available properties/methods and for most of them you'll also find associated reference documentation as comments.